# look up an explicit attribute name from the book 'Learning Python' by Mark Lutz

Tags: python, python-3.x

He explains looking up explicit attribute name from class C as follows:

```
2. From a class C, search the class, its superclasses, and its metaclasses tree, 
   as follows:    
    a. Search the __dict__ of all metaclasses on the __mro__ found at C’s __class__    
    b. If a data descriptor was found in step a, call it and exit    
    c. Else, call a descriptor or return a value in the __dict__ of a class 
       on C’s own__mro__
    d. Else, call a nondata descriptor or return a value found in step a
```

I understand all a, b, d and the part of c `or return a value in the __dict__ of a class on C’s own__mro__`
I don't understand the part of c `Else, call a descriptor`.
In b, it already checked data descriptor. In d, it's gonna check nondata descriptor.
Which `descriptor` does he mean here in c?
If you could give an example would be great